# JavaScript : How to detect if a node has been removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

I think the best way to describe my question is to create some image objects in such a matter:

```
<div id="image_collection">
    <div class="image" data-src="http://image1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image" data-src="http://image2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript I could have the following:

```
$('.image').each(function( index, element ){
    var image = new Image(); //NEW INSTANCE(S) CREATED (IN MEMORY)
    image.src = $(this).attr('data-src');
    $(this).parent().append(image);
});
```

Keep in mind this is an example in my real script `new Image()` is a custom object.

This script is done automatically so where ever I put `<div class="image" data-src="http://image1.jpg"></div>` an image will be created. Now some programmer uses this scripts and imports it and creates his own script with the following code:

```
$('#image_collection').remove(); //OR 
$('#image_collection').html('Some new content');
```

Now my script fires first and it will convert all images, creating new instances, but when the programmer removes the nodes within image_collection, my believe is those image instances will still remain in memory. How can I remove those image instances once they are not used in the DOM anymore?

Comment: Hmm perhaps you are right. If there is no reference nor are they used in DOM why would it still remain in memory. Perhaps I am over analyzing.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(this).replaceWith(image)`? That replaces the `<div>` with an image.

Comment: If you're really worried about not leaving a trace, after the line where you append, just do this: `image = null;` that will break the cycle and remove the reference. In other words Garbage Collection will do its work faster.

Comment: Why would you use that kind of logic in the first place? Just paste the img tag in the div container right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image() object is destroyed when the scope of $(.image).each() ends: actually, the 'image' var is created in that scope and it cannot survive after the .each() end.

So far, you have only the DOM node but it's removed by .remove().

You can feel comfortable :P

Answer (score 2):

The `.remove()` function removes nodes from the DOM and returns them. If you're not doing anything with the return value, they get cleaned up eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried about memory you can  put those images in a global image (or your custom object) array instead of putting it in a local variable.
Take a global variable

`var image_cleaned=false;`

Use timer  (i.e. setTimeOut ) to check if the din contains img tag with class `image`.
If it does not find any matching element (and image_cleaned is false ) then delete that array. Then set `image_cleaned=true;` . Then remove timer (optional but better).